# Logger Service need to have default config file for log4net / WISE

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation, setup-deployment, wise

I am developing a simple Logger Service (C#2.0) which logs message arrived (via MSMQ) from different clients. Logger Service logging mechanism is using log4net library. I want to have separate file for log4net configuration. 
Service is supposed to be installed together with another applications in one common installation package (using WISE).
I want that Logger Service will be provided with that default log4net config file at first installation and write that file on installation directory only if it is missing, otherwise keep existing file.

Please help the newbie.

Have i manage it in installation package or in service.. or in both places?
What is the best way?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlCconfigurator.Configure(FileInfo ... )
```

Allow you to specify a file other than the application configuration file. For the WISE setup: check the docs, I'm sure there is some options to don't overwrite existing files.

Comment: thank you - i know this option :) BUT 
Maybe i didn't properly expressed myself (sorry for my English) I want to provide this file as part of installation and TO NOT OVERWRITE IT at each installation if it already exists
I will check WISE, BTW - some alternatives..?

Comment: @ALZ I retag your question to be more WISE :)